# Mapping a value $g^x \bmod p$ to a small interval $[1...H]$

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, group-theory

My question is in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ context, where $p=q\cdot k+1$ for two primes $p,q$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$; $g$ is the generator of the subgroup $G_q$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$, of order $q$.

Let's consider a small $H$ (e.g. $H=1024$) and a specific $h \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, with $0 < h < H$, and we randomly choose $g \in \mathbb{Z}_q$: is it true (I hope it is) that it is easy to find a $x$ such that $h \equiv (g^x \bmod p) \bmod H$?

My concern is: is it possible to create a mapping from a randomly chosen $g^x \bmod p$ that can be mapped to a target (desired) value $h$ in a small range, such that we can find it easily, e.g., in $\mathcal{O}(H)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sample a random $x$, and $[(g^x \bmod p) \bmod H]$ will equal your target value $h$ with probability $1/H$. After trying $O(H)$ candidates you will find a preimage.

Fine print: Technically speaking, the probability isn't *exactly* $1/H$. Each $h \in \mathbb{Z}_H$ has either $\lfloor \frac{p-1}{H} \rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{p-1}{H} \rceil$ preimages under the mapping $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p \mapsto (a \bmod H)$. So the probability of hitting your target $h$, when you choose a random $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$, is $\lfloor \frac{p-1}{H} \rfloor/(p-1)$ for some $h$'s and $\lceil \frac{p-1}{H} \rceil/(p-1)$ for others. But if $p$ is exponentially large (as I suspect it is here since you're talking about discrete logs), then this probability is negligibly close to $1/H$.

Comment: Mikero, I've just started learning crypto by myself. I have to say that I didn't ask it, but the "Fine print" part was my real doubt! Please, which of 'Number Theory' I have to read to really understand the ceiling and floor bounds?

Comment: It is not really number theory, but simple counting. There are $p-1$ elements in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, and when you iterate over them in order, they map to $\mathbb{Z}_H$ in a regular repeating pattern. 1 out of every $H$ of them maps to your target $h$. But $(p-1)/H$ is probably not an integer, hence the ceiling/floor.

Comment: Just visualize $p=31$, $H=7$. $\mathbb{Z}_{31}^* = \{1,2,\ldots,30\}$, and reducing them mod 7 gives $1, 2, \ldots, 6, 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 1,2$. So 1 & 2 have 5 preimages and the other numbers have 4 preimages.